# Change of variable applied over a Binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable that follows a binomial distribution,

$$X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$$

and let $X$ be related to another random variable $Y$ so that $X=\xi(Y)$ and the inverse function exists, $Y=\xi ^{-1}(X)$.

In the case that $X$ is linearly related to $Y$, then will $Y$ also follow a binomial distribution? 
If so, how could the parameters of the new binomial distribution followed by $Y$ be found, $\text{Bin}(n_{_Y},p_{_Y})$? 
Would $Y$ also follow a binomial distribution in case the relation wasn't linear?

Comment: If $X=\alpha Y+ \beta$ and $X$ has a binomial distribution then in general $Y$ will not have a binomial distribution (with the obvious exceptions $X=Y$ and $X=-Y+n$).

Answer (score 2):

$Y$ need not have a Binomial distribution since its values need even be integers. Even if they are, the values need not be $0,1,2...,m$ for  any integer $m$.  We can only say $Y$ also take exactly $n+1$ values, namely $\xi^{-1}(i): 0\leq i\leq n$ and write down the corresponding probabilities.